# Inbox auto-read - a userscript to mark inbox notifications as read automatically

Tags: script, inbox

### Inbox auto-read

<kbd>[Install](https://gist.github.com/CoconutMacaroon/2bb587337fa2e8b7817e9a6704b4a793/raw/4fac995f8a648e47f8b20b97cbba810725860448/autoread.user.js)</kbd>

Tl;dr: This Tampermonkey userscript automatically reads inbox notifications when it is opened instead of requiring one to press the <kbd>Mark all read</kbd> button.

I gave it the MIT License, and [the source code is on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/CoconutMacaroon/2bb587337fa2e8b7817e9a6704b4a793).

[A change was made](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382693/inbox-improvements-marking-notifications-as-read-unread-and-a-filtered-inbox-v) to not automatically mark notifications as read (and require one to press a button). However... I personally prefer the old behavior of then being automatically read as soon as the inbox is opened, so I wrote a userscript to do that. See also [this MSE answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384149/1081494) suggesting an option to do that.

This userscript detects when the inbox button is pressed (by setting its `onclick`* to a bit of code that simulates pressing the button to read all notifications)

*The SE inbox uses events not `onclick` for the button that opens the inbox, meaning that the `onclick` property is free for me to use

Tested with Tampermonkey on Firefox, although this will almost certainly work on Chromium-based browsers too